# No hashrate when mining with CPUminer

Tags: mining, mymonero, hashrate

I've set up a monero-miner for my Raspberry Pi (for educational purposes) and when I run my miner deamon the log looks like:

```
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Using JSON-RPC 2.0
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] CPU Supports AES-NI: NO
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Starting Stratum on stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] 4 miner threads started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Binding thread 2 to cpu 2
[2018-06-28 07:58:10] Binding thread 3 to cpu 3
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] Pool set diff to 1063
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:11] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:47] Stratum detected new block
[2018-06-28 07:58:47] thread 1: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:47] thread 2: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:47] thread 3: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:58:48] thread 0: 0 hashes, 0.00 H/s
[2018-06-28 07:59:17] Stratum detected new block
```

I know that the Raspberry Pi is not optimized for crypto mining but 5-20 H/s should be possible. To start my deamon I use

```
./minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u <my address> -p x -t 4
```

as explained here: https://www.electromaker.io/tutorial/blog/cryptocurrency-mining-on-the-raspberry-pi-60

there it says:

> To start mining Monero, run:
>
> ```
> ./minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u youremail@address.com -p x -t 4
> ```

the money I mined is also not appearing in my wallet.. (neither on my MyMonero wallet nor on my MinerGate wallet)

---

What did I do wrong?

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it... I was using a 3-4 year old miner. The mining/hashing algo was changed in April (May?) I was using the old and incorrect miner, thus bad shares...

I installed a new miner: xmrig with the following commands:

```
apt-get install -y git build-essential cmake libuv1-dev libmicrohttpd-dev 
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
cd xmrig
mkdir build
cd build
CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt" CXXFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt" cmake .. -DWITH_HTTPD=OFF && make VERBOSE=1
```

Did this on a brand new Raspberry Pi 3B+ with armv7 CPU arch and new raspbian. Worked well. Getting about 9-10 H/s.

Answer (score 0):

You probably using a XMR Address with the XMO pool port. Change your port to 45700

Comment: Edited my answer. give that a shot

Comment: im not entirely sure what port it is, just scoped their website for a short period and noticed you had a XMO port in the perimeters

Comment: port 45700 is correct but the miner is not mining at all... it only promts if a new block is found and if i run the miner for 1 hour all threads are at 0 hashes...